# How to lowercase a string in CLEAN

Tags: functional-programming, clean-language

I have a problem in CLEAN, how can I make lowercase all letter in a string? I can do it through an char array, but i need to do it with a string too.
 I have the code below so far:

```
module Something

import StdEnv, StdLib

arrayLower:: [Char] -> [Char]
arrayLower[x:xs] = (map toLower [x:xs]) 


stringLower:: String -> String
stringLower_ = ""
stringLowers = toString (arrayLower s)

Start:: String     
Start = stringLower"SSSsss"
```

Comment: `String` is just syntactic sugar for `[Char]`.

Comment: i know, but still not helps, if they were eqvivalent semantically too then the code would produce "ssssss"

Comment: Is this question tagged right? At the moment it's tagged `haskell` and `functional-programming`. I don't know Clean, but in haskell it would be `arrayLower xs = map toLower xs` and there would be no need for `stringLower`.

Comment: Are you getting an error or incorrect output? What is the error if it's an error, and what is the output if you're getting incorrect output?

Comment: almost, there is not tag for Clean, but Clean is very similar to Haskell

Comment: the output is "", instead of "ssssss", that is my problem

Comment: unfortunately toLower is not working for String only just for Char

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first case

```
stringLower _ = ""
```

means that `stringLower` applied to anything is the empty string.
I'm surprised that you didn't get a warning for the redundant second case.

A `String` *is* an array (unboxed, so it's a `{#Char}`), and you say that you already know how to do this with arrays, but your `arrayLower` is defined for lists of `Char` (`[Char]`), not arrays.

This, using an array comprehension, works for me:

```
stringLower :: String -> String
stringLower s = {toLower c \\ c <-: s}
```

Comment: it's still not working:  Type error [Interleave.icl,6,stringLower]: near map : cannot unify types:
 String
 [v0]

Comment: @GaborToth How about this one? (Edited.)

Comment: i see, but the output is still "" :(, the complier says: Warning [Interleave.icl,9,stringLower]:   alternative will never match

Comment: @GaborToth Then you didn't remove the `stringLower _ = ""` case.

Comment: module Something

import StdEnv, StdLib

arrayLower :: [Char] -> [Char]
arrayLower [x:xs] =  map toLower [x:xs]  
 
stringLower :: String -> String
stringLower s = toString (arrayLower s)

Start:: String     
Start = stringLower "SSSsss"

Comment: so i removed, and i get: Type error [Something.icl,8,stringLower]:"argument 1 of arrayLower" cannot unify types:
 [Char]
 String

Comment: @GaborToth `[Char]` is a list, not a `String`. I looked through the manuals and edited the answer.